# Can we add two PATH in Environment Variables?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, path, environment-variables, windows-8.1

I'm using one System variable for JDK, second User variable for Microsoft VSCode.
And now I want to use **Flutter** in Android Studio, so can I add one more path in User variable???
Please help me with.

Comment: You can set a local PATH variable before starting the apps. Just google for it.

Comment: Windows 8.1 is no longer supported by Microsoft. You should probably update to Windows 10 (or something else).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can,

Click on edit existing Path variable like below image,
[image]

---

Then click on **New** to add a new variable,

[image]

---

**At last, don't forget to restart PC**